# Doubts regarding LSA

Tags: text, similarity, text-mining, lsa

I have to find the similarity between a reference document and the set of documents in a repository .

```
Method : 

1. I find the term document matrix for all the documents including the reference document 
2. The svd is calculated for this matrix 
3. I take the v array(The third result)
4. I transpose this matrix so that the each row represents a document . 
5. The first row represents the reference document . 
6. I find the cosine similarity beween this row and the rest of the rows
```

My doubts :

1. Since i have around 7 documents in my db , i get only 8*8 varray(document matrix) . SO will i get a correct result if i find the cosine similarity with these 8 values alone ?
2. Is such a method adopted generally ?

I use java to code this . I make use of the jama package to find the svd .

Comment: 8 documents is a VERY small dataset

Comment: ok.. but for finding the cosine similarity do i have to use the u matrix or the v matrix in the svd's (usv) matrix result ?

Answer (score 0):

- I have tried with Matlab using TMG tool box. It works fine.
- For better results ( or for more accuracy ) use larger data sets.
- In LSA , svd is a part of it ( For Dimension reduction ) . For
  calculating your Cosine 
  similarity, you will require the last matrix which you will get after this calculation
  A = U * S * V^t .

You can read an example of LSA [Here](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=latent%20semantic%20analysis%20%3a%20filetype%20%3appt&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDgQFjAB&url=http://www.cs.nmsu.edu/%257Emmartin/LSA_Intro_AI_Seminar.ppt&ei=LTIiT6r6EYLlrAenmJmhCA&usg=AFQjCNHt7rPgiFWBhkaoZoivdBRVc6XRjg&cad=rja)

Comment: Thanks ! but is it possible to use LSA For finding the similarity between two documents (No queries are involved) ? In that case should we consider the first matrix or the last matrix in the svd for  calculating the cosine similarity . Please help !

Comment: In SVD , we divide a matrix into 3 matrices. Again we need to multiply those 3 matrices and then we get another matrix which is approx. similar to A. Like A = U * S * V^t . And then we apply Cosine similarity . It is not like considering the 1st or last matrix. Follow the example which i have mentioned. Follow this link for cosine similarity : [link] (appliedsoftwaredesign.com/cosineSimilarityCalculator.php)
If you have anymore doubts then do tell me.

Comment: please look at my question[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060168/problems-using-jama-in-java-for-lsa) and tell me where i am going wrong